# I set up 11 test accounts for 11 languages to see how a client's appliction interacts with FB. Now, after weeks of testing, I'm locked out

Tags: facebook-authentication

We're now being prompted for 11 DIFFERENT phone numbers to associate wit hthe accounts upon logging in to provide a security code. We've already had multiple testers establish these accounts a friend accounts. Is there a different way to do this? Can I not have these accounts for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. Sounds like you haven't set up accounts properly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Edit:
Also see the bottom of this blog:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/612/

Comment: I would look at the blog post first. The first link is the general API info, the blog link shows you how to create users via the app settings.

Comment: I should be more clear here. We test apps for clients that have already been created. We handle the linquistic side of things. So, if you have a new app in English that works well and you'd like to localize it to 10 other languages, we handle the code but then need the ability to test as such creating 'friends' between the accounts, as they're interactive. I'm not seeing the solution with either of those links, unfortunately.
The blog is all about debugging. We cannot even get back into our test accounts without 11 different verification phone numbers.

Comment: We need to be able to replicate the 'friend' experience but these would only be linked within themselve. E.g., they friend only the other 10 accounts.